# SecItemUpdate failed to resume in time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, keychain

Upon UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, I trigger a SecItemUpdate call:

```
OSStatus itemError = SecItemUpdate((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)secItemSearchParams, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)secItemNewData);
```

I have one device (64 bit + iOS 7) that takes about 10 seconds to evaluate this line, and it returns with no error (OSStatus = errSecSuccess).

I keep getting a 8badf00d exception ("failed to resume in time" exception, see attached call stack), so as a remedy I moved this logic out of the main thread. However I don't understand why SecItemUpdate takes so much time to evaluate! It seems like the KeyChain or some other resource is not ready.

Any clues?

```
Call stack:
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
com.MyApp123.MyApp123 failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 3.670 (user 3.670, system 0.000), 15% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.022, 0% CPU

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000193d49cdc semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libxpc.dylib                    0x0000000193e006b0 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 180
2   Security                        0x0000000189f1157c securityd_message_with_reply_sync + 92
3   Security                        0x0000000189f21350 __SecItemUpdate_block_invoke + 300
4   Security                        0x0000000189f20228 SecOSStatusWith + 28
5   Security                        0x0000000189f211e0 SecItemUpdate + 136
6   MyApp123                        0x000000010059472c +[WDKeyChainUtils setKeyChainData:forLabel:] (WDKeyChainUtils.m:39)
7   MyApp123                        0x0000000100173e68 -[DateWatcher setLastSeenDate:] (DateWatcher.m:123)
8   MyApp123                        0x0000000100173ae8 -[DateWatcher watchLogic] (DateWatcher.m:96)
9   MyApp123                        0x0000000100173b68 -[DateWatcher watchOnAppBecomeActiveOrMainKeyDidBecomeAvailable:] (DateWatcher.m:101)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018711f5b0 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 16
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018706c100 _CFXNotificationPost + 2060
12  Foundation                      0x0000000187bfe744 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68
13  UIKit                           0x000000018a1b92e4 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 424
14  UIKit                           0x000000018a36161c -[UIApplication _handleApplicationResumeEvent:] + 1136
15  UIKit                           0x000000018a13532c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1876
16  UIKit                           0x000000018a134acc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 100
17  MyApp123                        0x0000000100266738 -[WDApplication sendEvent:] (WDApplication.m:38)
18  UIKit                           0x000000018a1a1040 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 668
19  GraphicsServices                0x000000018cd53500 _PurpleEventCallback + 672
20  GraphicsServices                0x000000018cd5302c PurpleEventCallback + 44
21  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018712ae8c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
22  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018712adec __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 440
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187129010 __CFRunLoopRun + 1616
24  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000187069c1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
25  GraphicsServices                0x000000018cd51c08 GSEventRunModal + 164
26  UIKit                           0x000000018a19afd8 UIApplicationMain + 1152
27  MyApp123                        0x0000000100110dc8 main (main.m:17)
28  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000193c67a9c start + 0
```